# rewrite in htaccess to new domain with language path combined with redirects of single URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

first i want to redirect a language specific domain to an other domain with a language string:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.de/fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this works as expected.

But in addition i need to redirect some urls to single pages to other pages:

```
redirect 301 /oldfrenchpage  https://mydomain.de/fr/newfrenchpage/
```

this does not work - combined with the upper rewrite it results in infinite redirects.

Any help? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this rules to the top of the .htaccess file (in that order)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^oldfrenchpage$  https://mydomain.de/fr/newfrenchpage/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.de/fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - very well to considerate www too. But the main problem is not solved: i get the error message that mydomain.de/fr/oldfrenchpage/ ist not found. So the redirect to domain + language string works but not the redirect to the new pagename.

Comment: I made a small mistake - i wrote RewriteRule ^/oldfrenchpage$ instead of RewriteRule ^oldfrenchpage$. It actually works! Thank you very much!